# How to disable selected visualstate FlyoutItem in .NET MAUI Shell

Tags: shell, maui, selecteditem

The MAUI Shell displays a blue vertical line to the left of a MenuItem after you click on it.  It also changes the background color to be slightly darker.  I'd like to disable that visual indication.

[image]

I did try [overriding the FlyoutContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#replace-flyout-content) and that does work but then I am stuck re-inventing the entire FlyoutContentTemplate just to fix this one thing.

[Changing the template for FlyoutItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#default-template-for-flyoutitems) does not work.  It seems that the styling for selected items is not part of the FlyoutItemTemplate.

[Changing the style of FlyoutItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#style-flyoutitem-and-menuitem-objects) also does not work.

Per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#default-template-for-flyoutitems), it looks like there is a visual state named Selected that causes this.  I'd like to eliminate that visual state altogether so there is no visual indication of a selected item.  Is there a way to do that?

Thank you for any pointers or ideas!

**Update:**

The issue is on the Windows platform only.  Looks like MAUI uses the NavigationView to render the Shell and [the WinUI NavigationViewItem does have a way to disable selectability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem.selectsoninvoked?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4).

So maybe the question I am asking is if there is a way to override rendering of the MAUI Shell on the Windows platform such that a MenuItem sets the SelectsOnInvoked property to false of the WinUI NavigationViewItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the blue vertical line to the left of a MenuItem in .NET MAUI Shell, you can override and set `NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground` to `Color="transparent"`.

Please add below code in **Platforms/Windows/App.xaml**:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="ShellFlyoutSample.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    xmlns:local="using:ShellFlyoutSample.WinUI">

    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"  Color="transparent" />

    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this very straight forward solution, works perfectly for my use case!

Comment: No worries, happy coding!